# Using Delphi 2010 to assign table-type input parameter in SQL Server 2008 Stored Proc

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2008

I need to copy records from Paradox-7 tables to SQL Server 2008. I have created a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 with a table-type input parameter. Using Delphi 2010, how can I send a Paradox DB table's records to this stored procedure? The tables already exist in SQL Server.

I tried this, but it gives an error regarding the paramater type:

```
VAImpTable.Open; // this is a BDE TTable component

 // spBatchInsert is a dbExpress TSQLStoredProc component

 spBatchInsert.ParamByName('@input_table').AsDataSet := VAImpTable;

 try

   spBatchInsert.ExecProc;

 except on e: Exception do

 ShowMessage(e.Message);

 end;

 VAImpTable.Close;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how it would be possible to have a SQL Server stored proc pull data from a paradox table on a client workstation.  How big are your tables?  It shouldn't be difficult to simply write code that adds one record at a time.  Alternatively you could write the paradox records to a text file on the SQL server and then use [bulk insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) to pull them in.

Comment: Thanks, right, the one-record-at-a-time will work, but tables are many and some are large - I'm sure the table-type sp input parameter method will be quicker and we have many clients with the same paradox db layout that all have to be appended to the single SQL DB